# Throwing an error to be deferred in Clojure

Tags: error-handling, clojure, deferred

I have some code that looks like this (d is manifold.deferred):

```
  (if throw-first-error
    (throw
      (d/error!
      (ex-info "Error"
               {:cause "first error"})))
    (-> (do-things-that-could-cause-error)
        (d/catch' (fn [e] (throw
                              (ex-info "Error"
                                     {:cause "second error"})))))))
```

The second error is deferred, which is what I want, because it is inside a `d/catch'`. How do I make the first error deferred too, so it can be caught be the function that calls this code by the same `d/catch'` as the second error. Thank you!

Comment: Put `d/catch` around the whole `if` statement?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! `d/error-deferred`instead of a standard `throw` solves this problem.